# Is there a callback function for Colresize in Jquery datatables when using colreorderwithresize.js?

Tags: datatables

I am using the colreorderwithresize.js plugin. Everything works fine, but most of the times the table is not getting aligned with header when the header is resized. I am trying to figure out if there is a call back function associated with resize such that I can call oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing() whenever resize happens.

I tried adjusting column width using fndrawcallback but this creates performance issues when filtering the data (since this is invoked every time the data changes in the table).

```
"fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {

setTimeout( function () {
oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
}, 3000 );},
```

Thanks,
Barani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kike table (CSS class) was overriding datatable (class) hence I was not able to use any of the datatables function on these tables hence I came up with a solution as below,

```
function resizeDataTable(dataTableid){
 $("#" + dataTableid).removeClass('kiketable-colsizable'); // Remove kike class
    var oTable = $("#" + dataTableid).dataTable(); 
    $(oTable).css({ width: $(oTable).parent().width() }); // Perform datatable functions
    oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing(); 
  $("#" + dataTableid).addClass('kiketable-colsizable'); // Add kike class
}
```

This works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting Allans' comments below for others who are in search of this feature......

Looking at the plug-in's code - it doesn't look like it, although I'm sure one could easily be added in the drag method.

I think you'll need to debounce (throttle) the call to fnAdjustColumngSizing one way or another though.

http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/13764/is-there-a-callback-function-for-colresize#Item_2